# Tapku TKCalendarMonthTableViewController tableview under TabBar

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, tapku, uitabcontroller

I have a TabController-based storyboard application with 4 different navigationController, one each tab.
The second tab open a navigationController(this still with storyboard relationship) which programmatically push a Tapku Library's TKCalendarViewController in this way:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    AgendaTableViewController *agenda = [[[AgendaTableViewController alloc] initWithSunday:NO] autorelease];
    [self pushViewController:agenda animated:NO];
}
```

AgendaTableViewController is a TKCalendarMonthTableViewController subclass.

The problem is the table view under the calendar goes under the tab bar and last cell is not visible as expected.
I think something's wrong with views or owner

How to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].frame.size.width, 368);
```

in loadView method in AgendaTableViewController(TKCalendarMonthTableViewController subclass).
Still looking for better width and height value in case device orientation changes.